# Decipher this puzzle

Tags: alphametic

This is my riddle for you, to solve it you need to decipher the letters to digits:

```
   j m b k
 + n h s m
 ---------
 n h b m t
```

the following rules must apply:

- a number can not start with the digit 0
- each letter is a unique digit

which letter represent which digit?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This isn't a riddle - I've changed the tag to the correct one for you.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling. There are online solvers for Alphametic's. You can also add a [tag:no-computers] tag the next time.

Comment: This is just the well-known SEND + MORE = MONEY remapped.

Comment: @MOehm Huh. So it is.  It felt familiar, but I didn't spot that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

> ```
>    9 5 6 7
>  + 1 0 8 5
>  ---------
>  1 0 6 5 2
> ```

That is -

> $\begin{array}{rclcrcl}\text j&=&9&~~~~~~~&\text m&=&5\\  \text b&=&6 && \text k&=&7\\  \text n&=&1 && \text h&=&0\\  \text s&=&8 && \text t&=&2\\\end{array}$

Explanation:

> **n=1** is obvious on inspection.
>  **h=0** is required because it can't be 1, and two digits don't allow carry+*h*+1>11.
>  **b=m+1** and **b+s>=9** because m+h=b and h=0 requires a carry  (b cannot equal m)
>  **j=9** is now required (it can't be 8 because **b=m+1** and **h=0** means no carry, so j cannot be 8).
>  Trial and error to fit the final digits suffices, since **m** appears 3 times and constrains things well.
>  We find with **b=m+1** and neither b nor m can be 9, 0, or 1, that **m=5** and the rest fall in line.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     9567
>   + 1085
>  ---------
>  = 10652
> ```

Explanation:

> It is obvious that n is 1 because you get a carry over from the thousands to the tenths of thousands.
>  This makes j 8 or 9.  Either one of these will make h either 1 or 0. But since 1 is taken, h = 0.

Recap:

> ```
>     jmbk
>   + 10sm
>  ---------
>  = 10bmt
> ```

Going on:

> In this case, j has to be 9 because 8 will not produce a carry over.

So now we have

> ```
>     9mbk
>   + 10sm
>  ---------
>  = 10bmt
> ```

and the remaining digits

> 2,3,4,5,6,7,8.
>  b+s is at least 10 (I would say at least 11 since m cannot be 1) and b is m+1.

Stabbing blindly.

> b = 8, would make m = 7

and this leads to

> ```
>     978k
>   + 10s7
>  ---------
>  = 1087t
> ```
>
> Doesn't work because s would have to be 8 or 9 which are taken.

Trying the same for b=7 leads to a wrong result also.

Now:

> Trying b=6.
>
> ```
>     956k
>   + 10sm
>  ---------
>  = 1065t
> ```
>
> This leads to s = 8.
>  Trying b=6.
>
> ```
>     956k
>   + 1085
>  ---------
>  = 1065t
> ```
>
> and the remaining digits are 2,3,4,7. 
>  Trying the different combinations we get k=7, t = 2.

Answer (score 0):

> It is:
>
> B=6 H=0 J=9 K=7 M=5 N=1 S=8 T=2
>
> 9567
>   + 1085
>
> ---
>
> 10652

Comment: Beat you by 11 minutes ;)  Good job though!

Comment: @Rubio Well, appreciate your effort